# Regex negative lookahead not matching last space

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have text:

```
test: [ABCD]
test: foobar
test:      [ABCD]
```

And I've wrote this regex:

```
test:\s+(?!\[ABCD)
```

So basicaly I want to find any occurence where `test:` is NOT followed by `[ABCD` and there can be any amount of whitespace between the two.

So for the first two examples it works as intended but I have problem with the third one: it looks like because of this part: `(?!\[ABCD)` the `\s+` is not matching last space if there are more than one. Why is that and how to solve it? I want to third example bahave just like frist one. Screenshot from regex101 to illustrate the issue:

[image: Failing regex]

Comment: Use `test:(?!\s*\[ABCD)` and if you need to match the whitespaces after, use ``test:(?!\s*\[ABCD)\s*``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the last match, as `\s+` can backtrack one step to make sure the last assertion is true.

There is no language listed, but is [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) are supported, you can also use

```
test:\s++(?!\[ABCD)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z5CNw6/1).

Answer (score 1):

You need the lookahead before the match with an anchor:

```
/^(?!test:\s+\[ABCD\]).*/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SGp640/1)

Answer (score 1):

You have one good answer to match the entire line if it follows the criteria, but based on this:

> I want to find any occurence where "test:" is NOT followed by "[ABCD" and there can be any amount of whitespace between the two.

If you want to only match the "test:" part, you can just move the whitespace character into the negative look-ahead on what you have.

```
test:(?!\s+\[ABCD)
```

Screenshot from regex101 using your example phrases:

[image: example of working regex]